# Running cases/if conditions in order in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

When I run the code which contains the below, if x is 3, it runs the instructions inside case 3 and quits switch statement completely. But I want it to continue with case 2 and case 1. However, if x is 1, it  should just run the instructions in the case 1(Like in switch-case without break in C/C++).

```
    switch (x)
           case 3
               k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(3),16));
           case 2
               k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(2),8));
           case 1
               k1= bitxor(k1,tail(1));
               k1 = k1*c1;
           otherwise
               disp('error');
   end
```

What is the most efficient way to run these cases respectively as I mentioned above? I must not use switch-case it can also be if condition.

Comment: What should happend in case 2? (break or continue with other cases) In case 3 you want do case 3 then 2 & 1, that's it?

Comment: In case 2 it should run case 2, and continue with case 1

Comment: It's not like in `C/C++`. From [Matlab doc](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html): "_When a case expression is true, MATLAB® executes the corresponding statements **and exits the switch block**._" If you really need to evaluate the other conditions even if a first one is _true_ then the `switch ... case` statement is not fit for your needs.

Comment: I meant I want it to run like in C/C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solutions here work fine but in both of them you need to repeat the switch expressions multiple time. You can define the order of them in an array and do the comparison once. Then a [`cumsum`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) helps you to enable the remaining switch cases:

```
s = cumsum(x == [3 2 1]);

if s(1)
    k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(3),16));
end

if s(2)
    k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(2),8));
end

if s(3)
    k1= bitxor(k1,tail(1));
    k1 = k1*c1;
end

if ~any(s)
    disp('error');
end
```

Comment: Definitely works! Elegant way of using `cumsum`, it obfuscates the code though. Timing showed on my machine that using `cumsum` is around 18% slower in execution. For a long if-chain and when execution time does not really matter, this approach is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would not change the value of `x` inside the if-statements like proposed by *HamtaroWarrior*. This causes side-effects and is **not clean code**! Better use the `||`-operator (OR) to catch the different cases like this:

```
if(x == 3)
    k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(3),16));
end

if((x == 3) || (x == 2))
    k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(2),8));
end

if((x == 3) || (x == 2) || (x == 1))
    k1= bitxor(k1,tail(1));
    k1 = k1*c1;
end

if ~any(x == 1:3)
    disp('error');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personnaly go for a `if` condition

```
if x == 3
    k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(3),16));
    x = 2;
end
if x == 2
    k1= bitxor(k1,bitshift(tail(2),8));
    x = 1;
end
if x == 1
    k1= bitxor(k1,tail(1));
    k1 = k1*c1;
end
if ~any(x == 1:3)
    disp('error');
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it is most efficient,  I will use this one

Comment: Changing the `x`-value inside the if-statement is definitely not clean code and should be avoided because it is a mere side-effect. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). Additionally it is less efficient than using the method in my answer. @Bhoke

Comment: And it can be added that a comparison in Matlab is done with the `==`-operator and not with a single `=` because it is used for an assignment. @Bhoke

Comment: Looking at your comments, I agree with what you said, I really take in count the side effect, the answers you propose are better.